# HTML/Javascript based Metro Style Boxes

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Im just wondering if anyone knows of any JS libraries out there that allow me to create a webpage with tiles/touch panels that function like the windows 8 metro/modern UI panels (also lays out boxes according to available page real estate). Basically wanting to make a metro style menu in my web application.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's a good question, not a very good fit for SO though, since there isn't one correct answer

Comment: you can use this http://metroui.org.ua/ and code.google.com/p/jq-metro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is an excellent one called MetroJS tha handles the tile animations. But it is up to you to manage their display on the page.
http://www.drewgreenwell.com/projects/metrojs

Works excellent!

I used this application to create my app Tweaker that is in the Windows Store, check out the free trial in the social category.  So it works great on Windows 8 too.

I was a little disappointed that the VariableSizedWrapGrid control is not available on WinJS
This is the control you want, to handle multiple sized tiles and wrap them all together neatly, unfortunately only available on XAML currently.
http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/08/windows-8-beauty-tip-using.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm using metroUI CSS (http://metroui.org.ua/windows8start.php) and liking it so far. Simple html, styled by CSS, lots of features, drag and drop js, etc.

Comment: This is my favourite for sure, anyone looking at this now should use MetroUI

Comment: Just note to everyone: this will not work with IE8 (only 9+), the js based solution mentioned above (metrojs) will work with older browsers. So keep this in mind if you need legacy support.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this recently and thought it was pretty awesome: http://tholman.com/projects/tileJs/

Uses HTML / CSS3 to get the subtle rotating window effect when you click on a window. That and MetroJS could be used in combination to get the effect you want.

Let me know what you settle on, I'm planning on doing something like this myself!

Answer (score 0):

Generally you're expected to use the Grid Application project.  Using a third party library like MetroJS means that as the platform progresses, you will fall out of date.

If you've ever used the Photoshop file picker, you know why this is not desirable.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try gridster.js . Here's a demo of it http://gridster.net/.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a fan of Bootstrap, there's this one called [BootMetro](http://aozora.github.io/bootmetro/index.html) which should be very familiar.